# Can the "ODBC call failed" error message be trapped and presented as a friendlier error message?

Tags: ms-access, error-handling

I have a MS Access database with a linked table pointing to a SQL Server instance over ODBC. If I try to insert a row which violates a foreign key constraint, I get a fairly ugly error message: "ODBC--call failed" with further technical detail.

Can I intercept this error message and present a friendlier explanation to the user?

Answer (score 1):

You could put the error handling at Form level, like this:

```
Private Sub Form_Error(DataErr As Integer, Response As Integer)
    Const conDuplicateKey = 3146
    Dim strErrMsg As String

    Select Case DataErr
        Case conDuplicateKey:
            strErrMsg = "Record already exists in the database!"
        ' TODO: add other error codes
        Case Else
            Response = acDataErrDisplay
    End Select

    If strErrMsg <> vbNullString Then
        MsgBox strErrMsg, vbCritical, Me.Caption
        ActiveControl.Undo
        Response = acDataErrContinue
    End If
End Sub
```